Unable to write Data from Kafka to Delta Live Table in Databricks
I have this code:
@dlt.table(  
    name="kafka_bronze",  
    table_properties={"pipelines.autoOptimize.enabled": "true"}  
)  
def kafka_bronze():  
    df = (spark.readStream   
        .format("kafka")   
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", {Masked})  
        .option("subscribe", "topic1")    
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")   
        .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 100)   
        .load()  
        .select(col("value").cast(StringType()).alias("json"))  
        .select(from_json("json", jsonSchema).alias("data"))  
        .select("data.*"))  
  
    return df  





However it fails and doesn't write any data. I can stream data into notebook successfully but with pipeline it's not loading the data. FYI I am using a unity catalog

when you say it fails, what is the error message?

Can you share your ERROR message here.

I am getting this error:
org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: [STREAM_FAILED] Query [id = --4476-8028-f268b475f****, runId = *****-bfb1-4383-b406-*******] terminated with exception: kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting to send the call. Call: listOffsets on broker 7

is there anything need to add for security protocol?

you code working fine. It seems like network related issue.

The error you are getting says org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException, specifically mentioning a TimeoutException from Kafka,
Indicates that your Spark streaming job is timing out while trying to communicate with the Kafka brokers.
I agree with @JayashankarGS can happen due to reasons such as network issues
Kafka broker overload, or incorrect Kafka configuration in your Spark job.
The below code helps you increase  the timeout settings for your Kafka:
.option("kafka.consumer.request.timeout.ms", "60000")
.option("kafka.session.timeout.ms", "30000")

I have tried the below code:
def kafka_bronze():  
    df = (spark.readStream   
        .format("kafka")   
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "your_kafka_bootstrap_servers")
        .option("subscribe", "topic1")    
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")   
        .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 100)  
        .option("request.timeout.ms", "60000")
        .option("session.timeout.ms", "30000") 
        .load()  
        .select(col("value").cast(StringType()).alias("json"))  
        .select(from_json("json", jsonSchema).alias("data"))  
        .select("data.*"))  
  
    return df

Results:

Name    Type
field1  string
field2  string

